# error occurs while running rake run:android

Tags: android, android-emulator, rhomobile, rhodes

I tried to run rake run:android the follwing occurs, kindly assist me.

```
AndroidManifest change file [C:/Users/giridhran/workspace/myfirst/bin/libs/relea
se/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3/extensions/AndroidManifest.xml] from native exten
sion not found !
delete original manifest
Manifest updated by extension saved!
EXT:  add additional files to project before build
PWD: C:/RhoStudio/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rhodes-3.3.2
CMD: D:/installer/android-sdk_r11-windows/android-sdk-windows/platform-tools/aap
t.exe package -f -M C:/Users/giridhran/workspace/myfirst/bin/tmp/AndroidManifest
.xml -S C:/Users/giridhran/workspace/myfirst/bin/tmp/res -A C:/RhoStudio/ruby/li
b/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rhodes-3.3.2/platform/android/Rhodes/assets -I D:/installer
/android-sdk_r11-windows/android-sdk-windows/platforms/android-8/android.jar -J
C:/Users/giridhran/workspace/myfirst/bin/tmp
C:\Users\giridhran\workspace\myfirst\bin\tmp\AndroidManifest.xml:30: error: No r
esource identifier found for attribute 'xlargeScreens' in package 'android'

Error in AAPT
```

Answer (score 0):

Before running `rake run:android` command, please ensure that:

- you have set the path of java-bin folder.
- you have set the path of Android SDK & NDK.
- check the android version in build.xml file.